# Save Windows Ink as transparent PNG image - missing highlighter strokes

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, inkcanvas, win2d

I'm trying to include Windows Ink in a UWP app, and started by adapting the [Windows Ink tutorial app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-tutorials-inputs-and-devices/tree/master/GettingStarted-Ink) to save the drawn strokes as PNG image (instead of GIF / ISF).

So, the XAML view includes a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkToolbar` and a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas`, and I'm able to draw strokes on the Canvas and save it as an image file through the following code:

```
IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> currentStrokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
if (currentStrokes.Count > 0)
{
    StorageFile file;
    // Using a file picker to identify the target file -> omitted this part
    if (file != null)
    {
        CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, (int)inkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas.ActualHeight, 96);

        using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.White);
            ds.DrawInk(currentStrokes);
        }
        using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            await renderTarget.SaveAsync(fileStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png, 1f);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine so far. Now, I'd like to save the image with transparent background, and changed the following line:

```
ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
```

Even in this case, the file is saved, the background is transparent, and ballpoint strokes as well as pencil strokes are correctly rendered - but the image result does not include any strokes drawn with the *Highlighter* tool.

Can somebody explain why these strokes are omitted in this case? Is it possible somehow to render Highlighter strokes over a transparent background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is the highlight strokes are transparent. When you clear the `Transparent` color. The highlight strokes will be detected not easily.
 For you requirement,you can set new `attributes` that with out the `attributes.DrawAsHighlighter` for `InkPresenter`.

```
private void SetHighLight()
{
  InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = 
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.CopyDefaultDrawingAttributes();
  InkDrawingAttributes attributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
  attributes.PenTip = PenTipShape.Rectangle;
  attributes.Size = new Size(4, 10);
  attributes.Color = drawingAttributes.Color;
  inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(attributes);
}
```

Add a new layer before calling `DrawInk` and gave it an opacity.  And made inkCanvas with 0.5 opacity specially for the highlighter, looking like you're using a highlighter.

```
private void GetCanvasRender(out CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget, float opacity)
{
    CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
    renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, (int)ink.ActualWidth, (int)ink.ActualHeight, 96);
    using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
    {
        ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
        using (ds.CreateLayer(opacity))
        {
            ds.DrawInk(ink.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());
        }
    }
}
```